# Delete characters with sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a File with.

```
10.32.59.15,5,RMI
10.32.56.15,7,RMI
10.32.30.15,25,RMI
```

I need delete with sed ",number,RMI" in all string:

```
10.32.59.15
10.32.56.15
10.32.30.15
```

I try

```
echo "10.32.59.15,5,RMI" | sed -e 's/,[0-9]+,RMI//g'
```

I need Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "10.32.59.15,5,RMI" | sed 's/,[0-9]\+,RMI//g'
```